# mysqlbinlog does not continue to last log

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I am using the following command to start reading mysqlbinlog.

```
mysqlbinlog -t -v -v --base64-output=DECODE-ROWS -h my_host -ppasswd -R mysql-bin.000960 -j 1052323996
```

I would expect the output to continue to the next log file, since I am using `-t`, but `mysqlbinlog` just exits.

How can I make this command continue to output log entries, like a `tail -f` would?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`mysqlbinlog` command's `-t` option does not work like `tail` command's `-f` option. With `-t` option, it will keep processing all the binary log files which currently exist. Once it reaches the end of the last binary log it will end, unless new data was written, before `mysqlbinlog` reached the end.

One such tool that will "follow" the binary log is [mysql_binlog_dump](https://github.com/jeremycole/mysql_binlog/blob/master/bin/mysql_binlog_dump). (I have not tried the tool myself.)

Looking at `mysqlbinlog --help` for MySQL 5.5, it says:

```
  -t, --to-last-log   Requires -R. Will not stop at the end of the requested
                      binlog but rather continue printing until the end of the
                      last binlog of the MySQL server. If you send the output
                      to the same MySQL server, that may lead to an endless
                      loop.
```